# js/jquery: how to load and display image sequences synchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some video in jpeg image sequence:

> part1.jpg, part2.jpg, part3.jpg, (...) part500.jpg

I would like to play them as a sequcence. I guess I need some synchronous events: do not display image2 if image1 was not loaded and displayed.

**What would be the best practise to play JPEG sequences of images ? (jquery or js solution)**

(let assume it is a 20 fps sequence)

Comment: Do you try/research anything?

Comment: I tried to change the src attr which is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to display them as a sequence but only after all images were loaded ? You can't make synchronous event such as pausing the script while an image is not loaded, but you can use asynchronous events such as :

```
var imagesToLoad= 500; // 500 images to load

$('img').on('load', function() {
    imagesToLoad--;

    if(!imagesToLoad) { // all images were loaded
        // run your carousel here
    }
});
```

The carousel will begin only after all images has been loaded.